# Thymeleaf - Is there a simple way to make radio checked based on condition

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using spring boot + thymeleaf and I try create list of checkboxes with minimum code.
Checkboxes present the all user roles (USER, ADMIN) and it must be checked if a user has such role.

So, at first, I tried to make it like this:

```
<p>
    <input th:type="radio" th:value="${role}"
          th:checked="${user.getRoles().contains(role)} ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'" />
    <th:block th:utext="${role}"/>
</p>
```

but it's didn't work.

Then I made it like this:

```
<th:block th:each="role : ${userRoles}">
    <p>
        <th:block th:if="${user.getRoles().contains(role)}">
            <input th:type="radio" checked />
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:if="${!user.getRoles().contains(role)}">
            <input th:type="radio"/>
        </th:block>
        <th:block th:utext="${role}"/>
    </p>
</th:block>
```

And this is work, but is there a simple way to do this like my the first try?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<input>` elements of type radio support common attribute [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#checked). This is the Boolean attribute which accepts `true` and `false` as the possible values. Said that your Thymeleaf condition can be placed directly into the value of this attribute as follow ...

```
<p>
    <input th:type="radio" th:value="${role}"
      th:checked="${user.getRoles().contains(role)}" />
    <th:block th:utext="${role}"/>
</p>
```

More on Thymeleaf [Fixed-value boolean attributes](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#fixed-value-boolean-attributes)

Comment: @AlexanderTukanov Glad it worked out. I'd like to point `th:utext` usage. This should not be used as the best practices, instead, you should get the habit to use `th:text`, where the text will be automatically escaped for you. Unescaped text may lead to some sorts of vulnerabilities. Best regards.